# bottleneck.move_mean get different result for the same ndarray

Tags: python, slice, numpy-ndarray, difference, bottleneck

import bottleneck as bn

import numpy as np

test = np.full((5,8), 0)

test[1, :]=1

the different result:

result = bn.move_std(test, 3, axis=0)[-1, :]

```
array([8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09,
   8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09, 8.60318943e-09])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: test[-3:, :] is full of 0, why the avg value is not 0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.